# Integrating real-time messaging in android app

Tags: android, quickblox, sinch, sendbird, applozic

I have been searching for a while as to what could be the best option to integrate real-time messaging in my app. I have read about a number of available chat APIs like Sinch, Applozic, Quickblox, SendBird, etc. What I am confused about is that since I am using Firebase Auth for user authentication, can I use these available API along with Firebase Auth??? I know I can even use Firebase to create IM feature but I would prefer to use third party IM APIs as it will save time.

Note: I am using Firebase Real-time Database as well to store user data.

Can anyone suggest me the best option in this case???

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

SendBird has simple and powerful Android SDK which runs very well with any types of user authentications.

SendBird only requires "user_id" to create a chat account and it should be super easy to integrate SendBird with Firebase by just using Firebase user unique id as SendBird "user_id".

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use both Firebase and Quickblox. Use Firebase to handle the authentication and use the FirebaseUser object to create a QBUser for your quickblox implementation. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As Norris pointed out in his answer, it is possible to use Firebase and QuickBlox, but QuickBlox requires client app to authorize with user_id and password. Since you can only get user_id from FirebaseUser object, but not the password (explained here: [Firebase/Swift 2 - How to get an authenticated users password and email](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36075602/4218640)), you could programmatically generate new unique password just for QuickBlox authorization and keep it stored together with other user data at Firebase Real-Time database. The user doesn't need to know this password, you just use it in your client-side code when you wish to authorize with QuickBlox API.