# Applozic with google firebase authentication

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, firebase-authentication, applozic

I have been researching for a while and found nothing about this. I am going to work on a Xamarin android app with integrated real-time messaging feature and looking at using Applozic. However, I am not sure how possible it is to use Firebase to handle the authentication.

Could anyone please give me some advice?

P.S. I have had a look at [Integrating real-time messaging in android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39066542/integrating-real-time-messaging-in-android-app)

Comment: I have seen a document before, and I wonder if it could help you :https://docs.applozic.com/docs/xamarin-push-notification

Comment: Thanks @LeoZhu
I think that was only for the push notification